# IF statement for % change in userform?

Tags: vba, userform

I have a sub, which shows the % difference between a current hourly/annual pay & new hourly/annual pay.

```
Private Sub txtNewPayRate_Change()
    Const HrsPerYr As Long = 2080                      'Work Hours in Year
    Dim CurrentPayRate As Double, NewPayRate As Double
    Dim PercentChange As Double
    On Error Resume Next
    CurrentPayRate = CDbl(Me.txtCurrentPayRate)   'current hourly/annual pay
        NewPayRate = CDbl(Me.txtNewPayRate)           'new hourly/annual pay
        If NewPayRate > 100 Then
            NewPayRate = NewPayRate / HrsPerYr
        Else
            NewPayRate
        End If         'new hourly/annual pay
    PercentChange = (NewPayRate - CurrentPayRate) / CurrentPayRate
    txtPercentage.Value = Format(PercentChange, "0.00%")

    If Me.cmbHourlyAnnual = "Hourly" Then
        Me.txtNewHourlyPay = Format(NewPayRate, "0.00")
        Me.txtNewAnnualPay = CStr(NewPayRate * HrsPerYr)

    ElseIf Me.cmbHourlyAnnual = "Annual" Then
        Me.txtNewHourlyPay = Format(NewPayRate / HrsPerYr, "0.00")
        Me.txtNewAnnualPay = CStr(NewPayRate)
    End If
End Sub
```

I come across a `percentchange` mishap when this scenario happens:

employee enters in an hourly rate in `CurrentPayRate` but then an annual figure in the `NewPayRate` section.

example: employee enters $25/hr in the current, but then enters $60,000 in the new pay rate because they're moving to an annual figure. This allows the % change to be something like 1000000% increase.

Unsure if this is doable to compare it and properly show the increase as if it were an hourly rate (even if an annual rate is typed in?)

Comment: Add in a checkbox to determine whether they mean hourly or annual? Or check if the value is something that will never be achieved in an hourly payrate. Then divide annual by 2080.

Comment: @Warcupine the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most likely nobody is paid more than idk.. 5000$/hour, you can add an if loop that determine if the entry is an hourly vs annualy rate :

```
If Newpayrate > x 'the max hourly rate you think about
 Newpayrate = Newpayrate/HrsPerYr
else 
Endif
```

Comment: I edited my post to reflect the changes, do they look correct?

Comment: The `Else Newpayrate` is not necessary and will most likely cause error (cause theres no = something) , you can leave the else empty. But yes it should work fine, try it with 4-5 values on different scenario using F8 and local variable and you'll see it unfold, accept the answer if it work so that the question's closed!

Comment: Is there a new event type I need to change to? I try typing into the newpayrate, and the second a number is typed, it triggers the sub.. this isn't allowing me to finish the number I'd like to type in